# Create dynamic param to ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need some advice. I'm trying to load some videos. The problem is that if I load two or more videos, I can't play them, only works if I load one.
I think the problem is because I need a kind of ID for each one.

How can I generate ID and pass them like a parameter of ng-click using angularjs?

Here is my code:

```
player.html

<div id="image-section" ng-click="click()">
  <div id="video-section" class="wide-rail-item" ng-if="ready">
    <div>
        <player content="content"></player>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 


directive.js

$scope.ready = false;
$scope.click = function(){
    
var showPlayer = function() {
    $scope.ready = true;
  };
}
```

Comment: Your need to hold a model structure something like videosArray = [{id:1, status: "ready", etc}...] so when you call click ng-click="click(id)"

Comment: Thank Panos! but what if its there is no limit? i mean i can load 2 videos or 100 or 200? Thank you very much!